# Linker errors when using SWIG to extendTcl with VisualStudio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tcl, swig

I'm attempting to extend Tcl by writing a few functions in C and wrapping them with SWIG.  All goes well until I try to build the C project with Visual Studio Express 2012.  Then I receive linker errors such as this:  "`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_Obj_SetVar2`". This implies that it can't find the Tcl.lib; I have verified that I have the proper Tcl.h and Tcl.lib files/folders specfied in Visual Studio.

I've looked for possible solutions, and discovered that I may have a 64-bit/32-bit issue.  I am running on a 64-bit machine; I tried this originally with Tcl 8.5 (64-bit version) and got the above errors.  I then tried uninstalling Tcl and installing the 32-bit version of Tcl 8.6, with the same results.  I am using SWIG 3.0.0 (not sure if that is 32- or 64-bit...)

I'm not sure what to try from here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be `__imp__Tcl_ObjSetVar2`; the other is definitely not a symbol that Tcl defines anywhere, and is probably a transcription error…

Comment: Quite right; I got an extra underscore in there.  My point was that the functions in the Tcl.lib file are not being recognized by the compiler...

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but I'm on totally the wrong platform and I've never personally used any of the Visual Studio suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the .lib and .dll files that come with Tcl 8.6 using the dumpbin utility it looks as if the Tcl library exports the symbol `_Tcl_ObjSetVar2`.  Your linker error refers to this function with an *imp* prefixed to it which is I suspect something that Swig is creating.

What would be helpful would be doing a search through all of the code generated by Swig looking to see if the function imp_Tcl_ObjSetVar2 is defined and/or referenced. To me it seems more likely to be a wrapper function that Swig needs rather than an issue linking to the Tcl lib which doesn't contain the *imp* export anyway.

### Update

As per the comments in addition to specifying the directory that the .lib file is located in you need to add the actual library to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependancies within Visual Studio.

Comment: I managed to find the offending functions in the Tcl library file (tcl86.lib).  This file exists in the folder (on my system) "C:\Tcl\lib", which I'm telling the linker about in Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories".  It seems as if I'm not properly telling the linker where the file is located.

Comment: As well as adding the library directory into the preferences you need to add the actual library to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependancies